# How to make background sprite responsive and only show half the height?

Tags: html, css

Probably one of the most documented subjects and yet I can't seem to find a proper answer for what I'm trying to get accomplished.

I have a sprite containing two images on top of each other. I only want to show the green one and have it be responsive at the same time. It is the background image of the whole page.

Please see: http://demo.chilipress.com/epic3/

I've given it a height: 900px because that's half of the height of the full img. I know it's not responsive as it is now.

HTML:

```
  <div id="background_contact"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#background_contact{
background-image: url('bg_contact.jpg');
width:100%; 
height: 900px;
background-position: 0 0;
background-size: 100%;
display: block;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean you want it to be responsive?

Comment: When I resize my screen, I don't want the blue background to show and at the same time I want the green background to be resized accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

An example is to have a hover effect on it, but you get the idea.

```
#background_contact:hover {
    background-position: 0% 100%;
}
```

If you don't mind the stretch, you can adjust your CSS to cover everything.

```
#background_contact {
    background-size: 100% 200%;
}
```

---

If you don't want it to stretch, you can use the following CSS, though you may want your own background color filler for the gaps:

```
#background_contact {
    background-size: auto 200%;
    background-position: 50% 0;
}
#background_contact:hover {
    background-position: 50% 100%;
}
```

Comment: adding the hover effect doesn't do it for me. But I understand that ou are trying to show the difference. I can still scroll up and down. I want it to show only the green one without being able to scroll up and down.

Comment: @Brain, this will probably help you get the right effect going to transition between the two. I adjusted my answer to reflect this change.

Comment: I'm using Chrome and a 15 inch macbook. When I open it up in View -> Enter Presentation Mode   I get to see it full screen and the size is correct. However when I simply click on full screen, I can still scroll down a little bit. 

Also The blue background is still showing if I look at it on my ipad both in landscape mode and in portrait mode.

Comment: You duplicated the `background-size` property, so the values of "100% 200%" is being overwritten by the duplicate property. (I'm looking at your updated version of the same site)

Comment: Ahh yes! I took the duplication out and put your code there. However on full-screen I can still scroll down and the height is not adjusted automatically to the window size.

Comment: That's cause the background is set to 900px height. You can try to make the body tag your background, and set the height and width of the `html` and `body` to 100%.

Comment: here is a great example of what I want to achieve: http://www.zorbixdesign.com/themes/horizon/

Notice that it resizes automatically in full-screen mode and in presentation-mode.

Comment: I put it like this 
<body>
        <div id="background_contact">
And set the height to 0
It's not showing now. 
I have been playing around with this for hours and no succes!

Comment: Obviously, if you set the height of a DOM element to 0, there's no room for a background to show!

Comment: Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sh2Yf/) with the basics. This works if you just want to switch between the two background colors. If you want to do [Parallax Scrolling](http://www.designerledger.com/parallax-scrolling-tutorials/), there's bunch of resources on that too.

Comment: I am purposely using a sprite in order to reduce load time. 
I understand I could use two different pictures to get the job done. But I'm sure it's possible to show one of the pictures on the sprite full screen and resizable.

Comment: 1. Your fiddle looks exactly the way I want it, however I can still scroll a bit down in your example. 
And please take a look at my page. The image is not showing and I have no idea why. 

2. I am not trying to do parallax scrolling. I want the page to load with a blue background / blue eagle and blue curtains (also in the sprite). After the form is filled up the background will become green / eagle green and curtains green. 

That's why I put the image in a sprite.I thought I could just load it later with jQuery, but at the moment I can't even seem to get it on the page correctly first place

Comment: To really reduce load times, you can do a single image, and apply a CSS Filter to alter the colors by using `hue-rotate()`. In that fiddle, I wanted you to take note of what is in action. Since that site loads everything into an iframe, the actual height can get wonky, and scrollbars get introduced. In your site you're missing CSS: `html { height: 100%; }` and `#background-contact { height: 100%; }`. A block element has 100% width of it's parent (upto parent paddings) and the height of the sum of it's children's relative heights. If no relative heights in the children, then height is 0.

Comment: I added the code you provided and it's doing what I had hoped for. However the sprites are not showing good with these settings applied on the image. So now I need to change the css for the sprites for all media screens. Is there no other way to get this done so that the sprites and the image are resized accordingly as was happening before?

I didn't know about hue-rotate. That's awesome, thanks for that!
No the height is in indeed 100%. But how would get get it scale accordingly with the width?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can try using [vh and vw units](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/). Instead of using percentages for sizes, you can use these units to reflect all types of screens. Play with them! Also, those particular filters are *webkit* only at the time.

Comment: I understand that when it scales accordingly with the width, the height is reduced and I'll probably get a white area below the image depending on the screen size.

Comment: Sorry, for a moment, I thought you were referring to the other divs on your page. But setting `background-size: 100% 200%;` for your background will force a stretch in both directions. An alternative could be to create another (oh boy!) version of the background for portrait oriented views to lessen the severity of the stretching in those views.

Comment: So here's the thing. 
I really need the image to change colours with hue-rotate on other browsers as well. So I guess that one won't fly for now until it's working on other browsers as well. But I really like this feature! 

The VH and VW units are something to keep an eye out for. It's new and  something I will experiment with in the future. thx for the link. 

So now that I am not going to use hue-rotate. What do you suggest I use or do, since I want the image to scale without the height going on endless?

Comment: And for portrait views I will either use a new image version that is appropriate or I might just use a very small piece of the background as a png and have it being repeated all over the screen. 
So the design will look slightly different on mobile phones etc. but it's still showing something that looks like the background.

Comment: I'm not sure what your view is on the stretching, cause the image that you have seems to need both left and right sides to look good. Like a double-edged sword, you need to choose between crop/pad and stretch, there's no clean way to have both. If you choose crop/pad, you'll worry about which is less important, the sides or top/bottom. You have the code for stretching. Cropping/padding the sides mean the height will cover completely and set `background-size: auto 200%`, and the other direction means changing the top-bottom orientation of the sprite to left-right and flipping all the properties